# Reduce com função externa

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar uma variável com o valor total dos produtos (`compraFinal`) e caso esse valor seja acima de 300 a variável `frete` deverá receber o valor `true`.

A variável de `preçoTotal` está com o valor `undefined` e ela deverá ser atualizada com o valor total dos produtos.

Preciso usar o `reduce`, porém, o meu ponto de dúvida vem agora, devo criar uma função que retorne o `precoTotal` e o `frete,` para depois atribuí-las as variáveis.

```
var produtos = [
  {
    product_id: '2350',
    product_name: 'Teclado',
    product_price: '650.00',
    product_quantity: '1',
    product_category: 'peripherals',
    product_brand: 'Rozar'
  },
  {
    product_id: '4566',
    product_name: 'Monitor Gamer',
    product_price: '1399.99',
    product_quantity: '1',
    product_category: 'monitor',
    product_brand: 'GL'
  },
  {
    product_id: '7112',
    product_name: 'Pacote de Post-it',
    product_price: '14.95',
    product_quantity: '5',
    product_category: 'office',
    product_brand: 'Fenix'
  }
]
```

A saida é essa:

```
compraFinal = { precoTotal: 2071.44, frete: true };
precoTotal = 2071.44;
frete = true;
```

Consegui chegar no preço final, porém, não sei como utilizar a função externa que deverá ser criada e fazer o retorno em forma de objeto na variável `compraFinal`

```
let compraFinal = produtos.reduce((valorTotal, item) => {
  const precoLimpo = +item.preco
  return valorTotal + precoLimpo 
}, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se eu entendi corretamente sua dúvida, talvez seja esse o caminho:

1° declaramos o objeto inicial `itemInicial` para você fazer os cálculos dentro do reduce, eu declarei ele fora para organizar e melhorar para você entender.

2° dentro do reduce somaremos o `precoTotal`, eu declarei ele separado para verificar se esse valor é maior ou igual `300` e também vamos aproveitar para atualizar o objeto que está sendo computado no reduce.

3° verificamos a compra final

```js
const produtos = [
  {
    product_id: '2350',
    product_name: 'Teclado',
    product_price: '650.00',
    product_quantity: '1',
    product_category: 'peripherals',
    product_brand: 'Rozar',
  },
  {
    product_id: '4566',
    product_name: 'Monitor Gamer',
    product_price: '1399.99',
    product_quantity: '1',
    product_category: 'monitor',
    product_brand: 'GL',
  },
  {
    product_id: '7112',
    product_name: 'Pacote de Post-it',
    product_price: '14.95',
    product_quantity: '5',
    product_category: 'office',
    product_brand: 'Fenix',
  },
]

//esse objeto sera a primeira iteração do reduce
const itemInicial = { precoTotal: 0, frete: false };
    
const compraFinal = produtos.reduce((itemAtual, item) => {

  //soma o atributo precoTotal + o atributo product_price do array produtos
  //também é feito uma conversão de string para float antes de fazer a soma
  //e por ultimo é feito uma multiplicação da quantidade do produto pelo preço, também é feito uma conversão de string para inteiro.
  const precoTotal =
    itemAtual.precoTotal +
    parseFloat(item.product_price) * parseInt(item.product_quantity);
  
  //aqui você pode fazer a verificação com qualquer valor desejado
  const precisaDeFrete = precoTotal >= 300;

  //após realizado a lógica você atualiza o objeto para o reduce computar o proximo item
  const itemComputado = {
    precoTotal: precoTotal,
    frete: precisaDeFrete 
  };
  
  return itemComputado;

 }, itemInicial);

 //ao final, você terá a soma dos produtos e também se deve possuir frete
 console.log(compraFinal);

 //a saida para a lista de produtos atual sera: 
 //{ precoTotal: 2124.74, frete: true }
```

ou você pode fazer assim

```js
//essa variaveel sera a primeira iteração do reduce
const itemInicial = 0;
    
const totalCompraFinal = produtos.reduce((itemAtual, item) => {

  //soma o itemAtual + o atributo product_price do array produtos
  //também é feito uma conversão de string para float antes de fazer a soma
  //e por ultimo é feito uma multiplicação da quantidade do produto pelo preço, também é feito uma conversão de string para inteiro.
  const precoTotal =
    itemAtual +
    parseFloat(item.product_price) * parseInt(item.product_quantity);

 return precoTotal

 }, itemInicial);

const compraFinal = {
 precoTotal: totalCompraFinal,
 frete: totalCompraFinal >= 300
}

 //ao final, você terá a soma dos produtos e também se deve possuir frete
 console.log(compraFinal);

 //a saida para a lista de produtos atual sera: 
 //{ precoTotal: 2124.74, frete: true }
```

espero que te ajude.